# Deactivating running/ready Tasks for Updates and Activating them again

Tags: powershell, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I need to write a Powershell script, that can deactivate all running/ready tasks on multiple Servers, so that we can update the software on those servers.

After the Update all the Tasks that were deactivated by the script should be activated again into the ready state.

Here is what i got:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxx-11, xxx-12, xxx-14 -ScriptBlock {Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \yyy\ | Where {($_.State -like "running") -or ($_.State -like "ready")} | Disable-ScheduledTask }
```

I am not so profound in Powershell (or scripting at all) to fathom how to get from the first part to activating those deactivated tasks again.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: The issue I see comes from the amount of time it's gonna take for the update. Is that also part of the script? It disables the tasks, updates, and then it's suppose to reenable the ones that got disabled? Unless, it's separate from the script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The script should not Update the software or something Fancy.

With the first Part i already disabled the running/ready tasks, now there should be a second part, that can be triggered seperately after we updated the software, that is activating the tasks i deactivated again. Not ALL tasks, just the ones that were disabled by the first part.